# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, when I launch the PreferenceFragment from preference-headers file

Tags: android, preference

1. This is my preference-header file that is used by SearchSetttingActivity:

   ```
     <header android:fragment="com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchableItemsFragment"
          android:title="@string/search_sources"
      />

      <header android:fragment="com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.DeviceSearchFragment"
          android:title="@string/device_settings_category_title"
      />

      <header android:fragment="com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchEngineFragment"
          android:title="@string/pref_content_search_engine"
      />
   ```

The 3rd fragment is added by me.

1. This is my SearchEngineFragment source below:

   ```
   package com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences;

   import com.android.quicksearchbox.R;

   public class SearchEngineFragment extends SettingsFragmentBase {

      public SearchEngineFragment() {
      }

      @Override
      protected int getPreferencesResourceId() {
          return R.xml.search_engine_preferences;
      }
   ```

   }

Everytime When touch the third item from PreferenceActivity, it crashed every time, the crash log is below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.quicksearchbox/com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchSettingsActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchEngineFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchEngineFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1117)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1133)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:532)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     ... 11 more
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchEngineFragment
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
03-06 23:10:48.133 E/AndroidRuntime(  803):     ... 17 more
```

please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
keep class com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.DeviceSearchFragment
keep class com.android.quicksearchbox.preferences.SearchableItemsFragment
```

Comment: Yes， I have done it. I defined them in proguard.cfg. thanks all the same!